# pgfplots significant figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, formatting, graphs

I'm trying to work out how to change the number of sig figs in the axis labels. I.e., I want the graph to display 0.0, 1.0, etc. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% horizontal axis
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=50,ymin=0.0,ymax=4.0,grid=both,minor tick num=4, 
    major tick length=0pt,
    minor tick length=0pt,
    %no markers,
    ylabel=Applied Force/N,
    xlabel=Length/cm,
 every major grid/.style={black,opacity=0.8}]

 \addplot [black] coordinates  {
(0,0)
(8,0)
(38,3)};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Assuming you want to change the y-axis only, add `yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed zerofill,precision=1}` to your list of options for the `axis` environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this by adjusting the style of whichever axis' tick labels you wish to adjust (`xticklabel style`, `yticklabel style`, or `ticklabel style` for both axes). Here I assume you wish to modify the y-axis tick labels.

The particular items of interest are

- `/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill` (fixed format with trailing zeros shown) and
- `/pgf/number format/precision=1` (display one digit after the decimal separator).

Since these are both in the same "folder", we can save keystrokes by using `.cd` to switch into that folder.

Putting this all together, we have

```
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed zerofill,precision=1}
```

which can be added to the `axis` environment options.

### Complete Code

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% horizontal axis
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=50,ymin=0.0,ymax=4.0,grid=both,minor tick num=4, 
    major tick length=0pt,
    minor tick length=0pt,
    %no markers,
    ylabel=Applied Force/N,
    xlabel=Length/cm,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed zerofill,precision=1},
    every major grid/.style={black,opacity=0.8},
]

 \addplot [black] coordinates  {
(0,0)
(8,0)
(38,3)};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: @JPing, glad I could help! Just for your info: The `cd.` isn't strictly necessary, it's just to save typing the full path for both keys.