# stacking plots, same x same y

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

I've plotted 5 plots individually, but I'd like to have something like in the picture:
[image]

where the y_max and the ymin is always the same and goes from 0.651 to 0.6535, but on different level like in the picture.
The x axis goes from 19.0 to 19:2.

'Till now I wrote only separately cause I can't make it work.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{url,amsfonts,epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{matlab-prettifier} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\fancyhead[]{} 
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}} 
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}} 
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\thepage} 


\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\parindent 0ex 


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,angles} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.6]
    \begin{axis}[name=plot,
    xmin=19, xmax=19.2, xlabel={$[s]$}, ylabel={$Ampiezza$},
    ymin=0.651,ymax=0.6535,width=1\textwidth]
    \addplot[blue,mark=.] table{10Hz.txt};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\textit{Oscillazioni a 10Hz}}
  \label{fig:10Hz}
  
  \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.6]
    \begin{axis}[name=plot,
    xmin=19, xmax=19.2, xlabel={$[s]$}, ylabel={$Ampiezza$},
    ymin=0.651,ymax=0.6535,width=1\textwidth]
    \addplot[blue,mark=.] table{20Hz.txt};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\textit{Oscillazioni a 20Hz}}
  \label{fig:20Hz}
  
  \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.6]
    \begin{axis}[name=plot,
    xmin=19, xmax=19.2, xlabel={$[s]$}, ylabel={$Ampiezza$},
    ymin=0.651,ymax=0.6535,width=1\textwidth]
    \addplot[blue,mark=.] table{30Hz.txt};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\textit{Oscillazioni a 30Hz}}
  \label{fig:30Hz}
  
  \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.6]
    \begin{axis}[name=plot,
    xmin=19, xmax=19.2, xlabel={$[s]$}, ylabel={$Ampiezza$},
    ymin=0.651,ymax=0.6535,width=1\textwidth]
    \addplot[blue,mark=.] table{40Hz.txt};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\textit{Oscillazioni a 40Hz}}
  \label{fig:40Hz}
  
  \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.6]
    \begin{axis}[name=plot,
    xmin=19, xmax=19.2, xlabel={$[s]$}, ylabel={$Ampiezza$},
    ymin=0.651,ymax=0.6535,width=1\textwidth]
    \addplot[blue,mark=.] table{50Hz.txt};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\textit{Oscillazioni a 50Hz}}
  \label{fig:50Hz}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Without a full working example, it is hard to demonstrate the remedy.  However, it is clear that, rather than having 3 separate `figure`s, you need to create 3 plots in the confines of a single `figure`.

Comment: sorry, I always forgot to add the entire code. I am also sorry that I can't upload the txt files I am using for this plot.

Comment: I did as you told me, but the image is obviously too large and I still can't figure out how to make them share the same x-axis.

Comment: You've tagged this with `groupplots`, which is a library for `pgfplots`, described in the `pgfplots` manual. Here is one example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309039/graph-with-multiple-y-axes/309111#309111

Answer (score 0):

that is great, thank you. I managed to do what I need. Now what I can't do is to use 4 decimals digit on the y axis:

```
    \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
 group style={
  group size=1 by 4,  % sets number of columns and rows in groupplot array
  vertical sep=0pt,   % vertical distance between axes
 },
 axis y line=left, % y axis line on left side only
 xmin=0,xmax=10,   % set axis
 ymin=0,           % limits
 domain=1:9,       % domain, just for example
 width=10cm,       % width
 height=3cm,       % and height for each axis
 scale only axis,  % disregard labels and ticks for scaling
 no markers, 
 enlarge y limits=upper,
]

\nextgroupplot[
    ylabel=$y$,
    ylabel style={at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},above,rotate=-90}, %move ylabel a bit
    axis x line=none] % remove x-axis lines
 \addplot{x};

\nextgroupplot[axis x line=none]
 \addplot{-x + 10}; 

\nextgroupplot[axis x line=none]
 \addplot{x*x}; 

\nextgroupplot[
    axis x line=bottom, % only x axis line at bottom
    xlabel=$x$,
    xlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:1,0)},right}]
 \addplot+[samples=200] {abs(sin(x*180/pi))}; 

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220969/pgfplots-significant-figures

Comment: thanks, I managed to do that. I just had to add these 2 lines:

Comment: yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed zerofill,precision=5}, %sets the precision
xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed zerofill,precision=2} %sets the precision